# pgAdmin - When trying to make a foreign key "referencing" gives no options

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have three tables: `ModelingAgency.clients`, `ModelingAgency.models`, `ModelingAgency.Bookings`. All three tables have a primary key column called `id`.

The table `bookings` has two columns that reference `clients` and `models`. In pgAdmin when I try to create a foreign key in `bookings` to either `clients` or `models` I get the following screens:

[image: Screen One]

[image: Screen Two]

What am I overlooking here? I am new to PostgreSQL (This is my first test project with PostgreSQL -- I've always used MySQL and occasionally SQL Server) so it's probably something obvious (I just don't see it).

**EDIT:** Here is the DDL, as requested:

```
-- Table: "ModelingAgency.bookings"

-- DROP TABLE "ModelingAgency.bookings";

CREATE TABLE "ModelingAgency.bookings"
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"ModelingAgency.Bookings_id_seq"'::regclass),
  "clientId" integer NOT NULL,
  "modelId" integer NOT NULL,
  "time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  "location" character varying(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No Location Selected'::character varying,
  CONSTRAINT "bookingId" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "ModelingAgency.bookings" OWNER TO "MyBatisTutorial";


-- Table: "ModelingAgency.clients"

-- DROP TABLE "ModelingAgency.clients";

CREATE TABLE "ModelingAgency.clients"
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"ModelAgency.clients_id_seq"'::regclass),
  "name" character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "clientId" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "ModelingAgency.clients" OWNER TO "MyBatisTutorial";


-- Table: "ModelingAgency.models"

-- DROP TABLE "ModelingAgency.models";

CREATE TABLE "ModelingAgency.models"
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "name" character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "modelId" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "ModelingAgency.models" OWNER TO "MyBatisTutorial";
```

Comment: What version of pgAdmin3 + OS and PostgreSQL do you use? Version 1.12 running on OSX using PostgreSQL 9.0 works fine.

Comment: It looks strange. Check if you're using latest minor version (8.4 or 9.0.4) of PostgreSQL and the corresponding version of pgAdmin3 (it's better to use latest version too).

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version and installed right before trying this. pgAdmin 1.12.3 and PostgreSQL 9.0.4.

Comment: Please post all your DDL code. I have PostgreSQL 9.0.4 and pgAdmin 1.12.3 on Windows 7 and it works well.

Comment: I can do that when I get home (approximately five hours). I know something just plain silly is being overlooked here...

Comment: Ok, the DDL has been added to the original post.

Comment: Try refreshing the database view (simply close/open pgAdminIII). The GUI doesn't know about new stuff you create via the SQL window - it has a cached view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into your posted DDL code I see that your table's names are written in wrong way (that causes your issue with pgAdmin):

```
"ModelingAgency.bookings"
```

It should be in format `"schema"."tableName"`:

```
"ModelingAgency"."bookings"
```

After that Object browser looks like this (probably you need to create schema first using easily pgAdmin or with [`CREATE SCHEMA`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createschema.html) SQL statement):

[image]

Here is working DDL code (I omitted some things like `OIDS` and `OWNER TO`, but that doesn't matter to your case, BTW `OIDS` are false on default):

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  "ModelingAgency"."bookings";
CREATE TABLE "ModelingAgency"."bookings"
(
    id serial,
    "clientId" integer NOT NULL,
    "modelId" integer NOT NULL,
    "time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "location" character varying(100) NOT NULL
        DEFAULT 'No Location Selected'::character varying,
    CONSTRAINT "bookingId" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "ModelingAgency"."clients";
CREATE TABLE "ModelingAgency"."clients"
(
    id serial,
    "name" character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "clientId" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "ModelingAgency"."models";
CREATE TABLE "ModelingAgency"."models"
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "name" character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "modelId" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```